# User accessing database files in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

Is it possible in SQL Server to find which users writing data in database files? For example: there are two users SA and microsoft\thomas on an instance. ABC database is accessed by both the users and it has three files ABC1.mdf , ABC2.ndf and ABC3.ldf . Can we find who is writing how much data on which files?

I need to to track users writing heavily on the databases as the disks become full because of them.

Comment: If it's a one off thing you can run use SQL Profiler. If this is a new feature you're going to need to write some sort of auditing functionality.

Comment: `.ldf` is the **transaction log** file - every user that uses your application will be writing into that file at some point....

Comment: Thanks. sorry for adding .ldf. I mean all the data files not the log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think its not possible to track which user writing how much data and on which data files.

Comment: Have you ascertained which database objects are in which MDF? What makes you think that a single user is the problem. It's possibly both users are using objects in the same MDF. PS You should write this stuff as a comment, not an answer.